# Keyboard layout not working on Alpine Linux 3.17

Tags: keyboard-layout, alpine-linux

I am running several Alpine Linux installations, some VPS via SSH, some on real hardware.

One of the machines (via SSH) can only input ASCII characters - e.g., pressing `Option` + `o` on my Mac keyboard types the Danish letter `ø` on all other machines, but an underscore `_` on one of the machines.

`/etc/conf.d/loadkmap` looks correct:

```
# Absolut path to the keymap which should be loaded using loadkmap.
#KEYMAP="/usr/share/keymaps/xkb/us.map.gz"
KEYMAP=/etc/keymap/us-mac.bmap.gz
```

This is what I also have on other machines. I tried to run the `setup-keymap` utility again, but without change.